# For loop in logstash

Tags: for-loop, logstash

I have an event in logstash that looks like:

```
{
   "terms" : { "A" : 1, "B" : 0.5, "c" : 1.6 }
}
```

I would like to change it to:

```
{
   "terms" : [ "A", "B", "C" ]
}
```

I didn't find any documentation about a `for` loop or get the keys of dictionary.

I would like to do something like:

```
filter {
  for key in [terms]{
    mutate { 
      merge => ["tmp_terms", key]
  }

  mutate { 
      remove_field => ["terms"]
      rename => ["tmp_terms", "terms"]
  }
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Logstash doesn't have a loop construct but you can use the `ruby` plugin:

```
filter {
  ruby {
    code => "event['terms'] = event['terms'].keys"
  }
}
```